# Java8 max compressed class space size

Tags: java

I'm running into a 3gb limit on my compressed class space size. I thought meta space was only limited by available native memory but it seems that's not the case for compressed class space.

This is a temporary thing - I don't intend to go to production with a huge compressed class space.

Comment: Don't compress. See [java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Compressed class space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30511439/5221149)

Comment: Thanks, for some reason the Oracle docs on this were confusing and it wasn't clear how to disable