# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace error after migrating to Java 8 from Java 7

Tags: java, java-8, out-of-memory

We got OutOfMemoryError when upgraded. The JVM settings are kept same as Java 7 which was working fine.

Here is the settings in Jboss 4.2 server:

> -server -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Xms4096m -Xmx7168m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom

Only difference in Java 7 is XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m was replace with PermGen max.

I wonder why it needs more Metaspace for class loading since the server & application is same & only change in Java version.

Comment: Do you have the stacktrace for the error? I would like to know the exact error for the OOM.

Comment: can you provide exact Java parameters when you start the JBoss with Java 8?

Comment: Java params used are added in quersion: -server -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Xms4096m -Xmx7168m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom

Answer (score 8):

You should probably remove `-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m` altogether.

My guess is, that in Java 7 you've needed to *increase* the permanent generation to get things to run at all, because the default max was too low.

In Java 8, the metaspace that holds your classes can expand without limit by default, so you probably don't run into the issue you have tried to solve for Java 7 in the first place. Instead, as you have experienced, you run into another issue: Setting too low a metaspace limit. Removing said limit will probably solve the issue and allow the JVM to make suitable decisions for you.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31463972/942774).

Comment: Removing MaxMetaspaceSize caused increase in Metaspace usage upto 3g. Since the server had 8g & max heap allocated in 7g, got another memory crash. Is dead classloaders in metaspace garbage collected? Os there any settings to control that?

Comment: You could try setting `-XX:MaxMetaspaceExpansion=0` to force meta space garbage collections (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/31632341/942774), but if anyone still holds on to your class objects, it won't do much good.

Comment: The result is same even after setting -XX:MaxMetaspaceExpansion=0. total = 1394    27716   53490569            N/A         alive=1, dead=1393          N/A. I see garbage collection run in frequent intervals on non-heap memory. I wonder why these much dead class loaders then?

Comment: This sounds like you need to debug a class loading memory leak. Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/a/37933050/942774 helps a little. At this point I would search the web for JBoss 4.2 class loading issues on Java 8. YMMV, as v4.2 is older than Java 8. Perhaps it's time to update JBoss.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that comes to my mind is that java8 uses lambdas and every lambda is some sort of class in java 8. Correct me if im wrong but thats what my inspection sees when creating class chart of a java8 app. Thus java8 uses more class memory.